# Textures doesn’t work on some versions Safari (Ventura 16.5)

Tags: safari, textures, render

**The code doesn’t work on some of versions Safari (16.5 for example). What is the reason? Please see screenshots**

```
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const mapTexture = textureLoader.load('src/img/textures/map_lines_dots.jpg');

    const backgroundTexture = textureLoader.load('src/img/textures/background.svg');
    scene.background = backgroundTexture;

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 3;

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; // Enable shadow mapping
    document.getElementById("scene-container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera.rotation.z = Math.PI /-7;

    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 50,50);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: mapTexture ,
        opacity: 0.8,
        transparent: true
    });
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    sphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    sphere.castShadow = true;
    sphere.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(sphere);

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
    light.position.set(3, 2, 5);
    light.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(light);

    const animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        sphere.rotation.x = 0.3;
        sphere.rotation.y += 0.0025;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });
```

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXyKu.jpg)

What can you advise me to do?

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.

Comment: The problem in some versions of Safari (Ventura for example)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (1497x930) to (1024x512).
THREE.WebGLState - TypeError
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () (805433a8eb7c212, line 0)